# Modify image after downloading it via AFNetworking and set it to tableview cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking-2

I am using `AFNetworking` to download images for tableview cells.

Since I need to do some modification after getting the image from the Internet, I use the following code:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];

[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    UIImage *newImage = [self modifyImage:responseObject];

    [imageView setImage:newImage];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
}];
```

I am sure the `success block` was executed, but the image doesn't show when the first time I load the `tableview`. If I use `[self.tableView reloadData]` afterwards, the image shows.

If I use the following code, it will show immediately without `[self.tableView reloadData]` though (of course without my modification):

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:url]
```

How do I modify an image after downloading it correctly?

**edit**

Here is my code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl];
[request addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[_postImageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    CGFloat originalImageWidth = image.size.width;
    CGFloat originalImageHeight = image.size.height;
    CGFloat ratio = _postImageView.frame.size.width/originalImageWidth;

    CGFloat newImageWidth = originalImageWidth;
    CGFloat newImageHeight = originalImageHeight * ratio;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newImageWidth, newImageHeight));
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newImageWidth, newImageHeight)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       _postImageView.image = newImage;
    });
} failure:nil];
```

But there is no luck, I still need to reload the tableview to show the image.

Comment: `[imageView setImage:newImage];` Is this running on main thread ?

Comment: To set the image on main thread, just enclose dispatch async with main thread :     `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{    [imageView setImage:newImage];
});`

Comment: What code is in [self modifyImage:]?

Comment: Use UIImageView+AFNetworking's - (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
              placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error))failure and modify in success message and set image

Comment: Thank you guys for giving me these clues, I've tried your suggestions (see my updated questions), but I still need to reload my tableview to show the image. Can you give me further helps?

Answer (score -1):

**Here We added demo code for you. May be it’s helpful for you. Here We First Access main image then after we do some modification, In my case i add water mark image on it. Then After i will be set image on image view. If you need more help then let us know.**

```
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];

    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        UIImage *newImage = [self modifyImage:responseObject];
    //Modification - Add water mark Image on Main Image - Do Some Stuff Here
        UIImage *watermarkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermark_image.png"];

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImage.size);
        [newImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newImage.size.width, newImage.size.height)];
        [watermarkImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newImage.size.width, newImage.size.height)];
        UIImage *resultImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//Your Modified Image (resultImg) set in Imageview/Tableviewcell -Whatever      
        [imageView setImage:resultImg];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Answer (score -1):

What about using this method of UIImageView+AFNetworking category:

```
- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
          placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
                   success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image))success
                   failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error))failure;
```

Because as you can read it [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h):

"If a success block is specified, it is the responsibility of the block to set the image of the image view before returning. If no success block is specified, the default behavior of setting the image with `self.image = image` is applied."
So you can modify the image with your custom method and I think you will have the same behaviour than:

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:url]
```

If it doesnt work you can try to call `setNeedsLayout` on your cell. In your code it will look like:

```
__weak MyCell *weakCell = self; // I assume self is your cell but i'm not sure
[_postImageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    CGFloat originalImageWidth = image.size.width;
    CGFloat originalImageHeight = image.size.height;
    CGFloat ratio =     _postImageView.frame.size.width/originalImageWidth;

    CGFloat newImageWidth = originalImageWidth;
    CGFloat newImageHeight = originalImageHeight * ratio;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newImageWidth, newImageHeight));
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newImageWidth, newImageHeight)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    weakCell.postImageView.image = newImage;
    [weakCell setNeedsLayout];
} failure:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me these clues, I've tried your suggestion, but I still need to reload my tableview to show the image. (See my updated questions). Can you give me further helps?